# Generate random bar codes - a design issue

Tags: java, database, multithreading

I'm fixing bugs (thread issues) in java code that generate bar codes. As per design the barcode is just a number and the next "not used" bar code is next in the sequence. There are 99 billion possible numbers.

First of all I don't like auto incremented numbers because of security issues. I want to generate random numbers.

Already used bar codes are stored in a database table.

It is quite easy to create a random number and check against the table if the barcode is in use. But the logic will have to loop until it finds a random number is not in use. By time this could be a heavy task.

I think that a thread safe cache with 1000 free bar codes would do the job, but building or renewing the cache can be quite heavy.

Any suggestions to a design of a query that does the lookup or a query that can return a range of free random numbers?

I'm using hibernate criterias.

Thanks

Comment: Don't worry about it. If you use a function that generates random numbers uniformly, then the possibility of generating the same number (out of 99 billion possible numbers) is extremely low. So you will have 1 random number generation and 1 db lookup, which is not big overhead

Comment: You could minimise clashes by using the date or parts of the date in the barcode and fewer random digits. i.e. 15 + 9 random digits or 1501 + 7 random digits.

Comment: It depends on how many barcodes the system will generate, ever. If the system generates 990 million barcodes, then the next barcode will have just a 1% chance of clashing, so @mavroprovato is pretty much right. But if you're generating 50 billion barcodes, you'll have more than a 50% clash rate (and a 25% chance of clashing on the second try, etc). So what's the design scale here?

Answer (score 4):

You could use a [Linear Feedback Shift Register](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register). They can step through all numbers with a specific number of bits in a cycle without repeating but in a seemingly random order.

This should work - it is a severely cut-down version of one I wrote a while ago. You will have to choose your primitive polynomial as described in the links.

You can find a list of randomly chosen primitive polynomials [here](http://www.jjj.de/mathdata/rand-primpoly.txt).

```
/**
 * Linear feedback shift register
 *
 * Taps can be found at: 
 * See http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp052.pdf 
 * See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/46961/how-are-taps-proven-to-work-for-lfsrs/46983#46983
 * See http://www.newwaveinstruments.com/resources/articles/m_sequence_linear_feedback_shift_register_lfsr.htm 
 * See http://www.yikes.com/~ptolemy/lfsr_web/index.htm 
 * See http://seanerikoconnor.freeservers.com/Mathematics/AbstractAlgebra/PrimitivePolynomials/overview.html 
 *
 * @author OldCurmudgeon
 */
public class LFSR implements Iterable<BigInteger> {

    // Bit pattern for taps.
    private final BigInteger taps;
    // Where to start (and end).
    private final BigInteger start;

    // The poly must be primitive to span the full sequence.
    public LFSR(BigInteger primitivePoly, BigInteger start) {
        // Where to start from (and stop).
        this.start = start.equals(BigInteger.ZERO) ? BigInteger.ONE : start;
        // Knock off the 2^0 coefficient of the polynomial for the TAP.
        this.taps = primitivePoly.shiftRight(1);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<BigInteger> iterator() {
        return new LFSRIterator(start);
    }

    private class LFSRIterator implements Iterator<BigInteger> {
        // The last one we returned.

        private BigInteger last = null;
        // The next one to return.
        private BigInteger next = null;

        public LFSRIterator(BigInteger start) {
            // Do not return the seed.
            last = start;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            if (next == null) {
                /*
                 * Uses the Galois form.
                 *
                 * Shift last right one.
                 *
                 * If the bit shifted out was a 1 - xor with the tap mask.
                 */
                boolean shiftedOutA1 = last.testBit(0);
                // Shift right.
                next = last.shiftRight(1);
                if (shiftedOutA1) {
                    // Tap!
                    next = next.xor(taps);
                }
                // Never give them `start` again.
                if (next.equals(start)) {
                    // Could set a finished flag here too.
                    next = null;
                }
            }
            return next != null;
        }

        @Override
        public BigInteger next() {
            // Remember this one.
            last = hasNext() ? next : null;
            // Don't deliver it again.
            next = null;
            return last;
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported.");
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return LFSR.this.toString()
                    + "[" + (last != null ? last.toString(16) : "")
                    + "-" + (next != null ? next.toString(16) : "") + "]";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + taps.toString(32) + ")-" + start.toString(32);
    }

}

public void test(int[] tap, int base) {
    System.out.println("Test: " + Arrays.toString(tap));
    // Build the BigInteger.
    BigInteger primitive = BigInteger.ZERO;
    for (int bit : tap) {
        primitive = primitive.or(BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(bit));
    }
    // Stop at 100.
    int count = 100;
    LFSR lfsr = new LFSR(primitive, BigInteger.ONE);
    for (BigInteger b : lfsr) {
        if (count-- > 0) {
            System.out.println(b.toString(base));
        } else {
            break;
        }

    }
}

public void test() {
    // Just 6 bits.
    int[] tap7 = {6, 5, 0};
    test(tap7, 10);
    // An example 48-bit tap.
    int[] tap48 = {48, 46, 45, 44, 42, 40, 36, 34, 33, 32, 29, 27, 26, 20, 17, 16, 12, 11, 10, 5, 3, 1, 0};
    test(tap48, 16);
}
```