# Performant way to select N random distinct ints in java?

Tags: java, random

I currently am looking for the best way so select x unique ints among a range of n ints. It would be like doing `Random.nextInt(range)` multiple time except it should never select twice the same int.
If it happens that `x > n` then the result would only contain n ints

I tried to do this myself and I currently have done this based on the Fisher/Yates shuffle:

```java
private static final Random R   = new Random();

public static int[] distinctRandoms(int nb, int max) {
    int[] all = new int[max];
    for (int i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
        all[i] = i;
    }
    if (max <= nb) {
        return all;
    }
    int index;
    int[] result = new int[nb];

    for (int j = 0, k = all.length - 1; k > 0 && j < nb; k--, j++) {
        index = R.nextInt(k + 1);
        result[j] = all[index]; // save element
        all[index] = all[k]; // overwrite chosen with last element
    }
    return result;
}
```

It works and performance seems good but I can't help thinking there must still be some more performant way to do so and that i'm reinventing the wheel. I thought about doing things differently if `nb > (max / 2)` (remove elements rather than select elements) but as you can't truncate an array in java you still end up copying all the elements you need.
This method costs alot if `nb = max-1`

Is there any built in way to randomly select distinct ints efficiently in java ?

**Edit 1:**

What I mean by performant is time-efficient. I want it to be fast. I'll mostly work with small sets of randoms.

**Edit 2:**

I tried using shuffle like that but it's much more expensive in terms of time because of all the extra object creation.

```
public static Integer[] distinctRandoms2(int nb, int max) {
    ArrayList<Integer> all = new ArrayList<Integer>(max);
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        all.add(i);
    }
    if (max <= nb) {
        return all.toArray(new Integer[max]);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(all);
    return all.subList(0, nb).toArray(new Integer[nb]);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `performant`? Memory usage? CPU performance? Are you looking for the most perormant solution there is, or for one that is performant enough for a certain job?

Comment: If x and n are close, you can't do much better than a partial Fisher-Yates. That is, fill the array with all n, then do x passes of FY. If x is very much smaller than n, then you might consider Floyd's algorithm.

Comment: By "small sets of randoms", do you mean that `max` is small or `nb` is small? If `max` is small, the shuffle approach is fine, if it can be arbitrary large but `nb` is small then the `HashSet` option should be good (although you will have some boxing/unboxign cost).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [shuffle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) method from `java.util.Collections` class.

Just create list of Integers from `0` to `x-1`, then call `shuffle` method on it and take first `nb` elements.

Using `shuffle` method has sense when `nb` is close to `max`. So it would be good for following pairs of parameters:

- `nb=70, max=100`
- `nb=900, max=1000`
- `nb=9000, max=10000`

but not so good for:

- `nb=10, max=10^8`
- `nb=100, max=10^9`

It would be a good idea to combine above method (using `shuffle`) with Floyd's algorithm from other answer. Selection of algorithm should be based on ratio `nb/max`. Border ratio should be chosen carefully.

Comment: This uses the `Fisher/Yates` algorithm so is a good alternative to the do-it-yourself OP posted.

Comment: Thanks. I have tested this but the cost of collection initialization + subList + toArray takes much more time than the solution i currently have. I'll edit my question to show what i tried.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Floyd's algorithm. It is much more efficient than shuffling if the number of elements to be selected is smaller than their range.

```
private static final Random random = new Random();

/**
 * Converts a set of Integer to an array of int.
 */
private static int[] setToArray(Set<Integer> aSet) {
    int[] result = new int[aSet.size()];
    int index = 0;
    for (int number : aSet) {
        result[index] = number;
        index++;
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * Generates an array of min(count, maxValue) distinct random ints 
 * from [0, maxValue - 1] range.
 * @param count The number of elements to be generated.
 * @param maxValue The upper bound of the range(exclusively).
 */
public static int[] getDistinctRandomNumbers(int count, int maxValue) {
    Set<Integer> was = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = Math.max(0, maxValue - count); i < maxValue; i++) {
        int curr = i == 0 ? 0 : random.nextInt(i);
        if (was.contains(curr))
            curr = i;
        was.add(curr);
    }
    return setToArray(was);
}
```

It has `O(count)` time and space complexity, where `count` is number of distinct integers that should be generated.

Comment: If there was no `Collections#shuffle` method, then I would do it with a Set too, but the `Set#contains` performance greatly depends on the Set implementation, so you cant say for sure, that it has linear complexity

Comment: @bali182 It is much better than `Collections.shuffle` if the range is big but the number of elements we should generate is small, because its time and space complexity depends linearly on the number of elements to be generated, not the range size(for example, if `count = 100` and `maxValue is `10^9`).

Comment: Thanks but I'm having the same problem as with Collections.shuffle here. The extra time for object creation / conversion costs too much compared to my initial solution.

Comment: @Crystark I think using a hash set with primitives from a third-party library(or implementing your own version if you cannot use anything except the Java standard library) should help.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by `Performant` and `Random`.

If you really are in need of something that costs `O(1)` or similar then you could use a [Linear feedback shift register](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register) or [LFSR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27781764/823393). It generates a random-like sequence of numbers (i.e. statistically random but theoretically predictable) using a simple `XOR` operation on the previous number and is thus probably the fastest mechanism possible.

This approach is most appropriate if you want any n-bit number. Limiting the number range by discarding those outside the required range may reduce performance.

Comment: I've taken a look at this and tested some code and it seems interesting though I'm not sure I understand everything. How would i be able to bound the int to values between 0 and 9 for instance ?

Comment: @Crystark - For 0-9 you would need a 4-bit LFSR giving you a range of 1-15. Then just subtract 1 (you never get a zero out of an lfsr) and discard anything > 9. It's fiddly but **very** fast. Note that you will always get the same sequence from the same tap. I would pick a random tap out of a pre-calculated set as calculating taps on the fly is not trivial.

Answer (score 1):

If by "small sets of randoms" you mean that `max` is small, the `Collections#shuffle` approach is probably as good as you can get.

If `max` can be arbitrary large but `nb` is small then using a `HashSet` may be your best option, although you will have some boxing/unboxign cost. If you want to avoid that cost, you can try using [an `IntHashSet`](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/set/hash/TIntHashSet.html) or a similar primitive specialisation of `HashSet`.